# How to redirect connections by an exe file to a specific external ip address

Tags: windows-10, ip-address, firewall, windows-defender

- I have an exe program that connects randomly to one of the 4 addresses 188.39.21.82...83...84...85 out of which only 82 works
- Currently I blocked the remaining addresses using Windows 10 Firewall outbound rules by simply blocking them
- My problem is that the program will keep attempting to connect say 10-20 times (times out after 20 seconds each time) before it finally connects to the IP address ending with 82
- Is there a way that I can write a rule such that the program will get redirected to the IP address ending with 82 regardless of which IP it attempts to connect with?
- Example: the program tries to connect to 188.39.21.85 but gets redirect to 188.39.21.82
- I want to add that all the IP addresses actually work but the exe file doesnt work properly on any of them except the one ending with 82

Answer (score 2):

Try using Netsh's `add v4tov4` (found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1102555/how-can-i-do-dnat-and-snat-on-windows-7) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc731068(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)) to proxy outgoing connections  from the range 188.39.21.83 - 188.39.21.85 (You don't need to include 82 since it works) to go directly to the working host. Only TCP is supported though.

`add v4tov4listenport=[port] connectaddress=[188.39.21.82] connectport=[port]  listenaddress=[not working IPs]`

Note that you may not be able to list `listenaddress` to multiple addresses in one command, so you might have to change the IP and execute it again.

Comment: any recommendations for UDP? just used a network packet inspector and all traffic seems to be UDP

Comment: Check the other answer and look up how to port forward on your router.

Answer (score 1):

you may as well login to your home router
go to port forwarder section usually located on network / advanced setting .
from there you can redirect requests from port to another .
to access your router usually its the gateway numbber .
you can run cmd and type
ipconfig / all
it will show the internet gateway.

Answer (score 0):

you could setup the virtual host for redirecting the traffic.

1.go to Windows > Search > Run and paste the following line
`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

2. In the file type

```
<destination_ip> <source_ip>
```

3. save the file
   eg in your case

```
188.39.21.82 188.39.21.85
```

now all traffic from `188.39.21.85` will redirect to `188.39.21.82`
similarly you can redirect all ips traffic to `188.39.21.82`

Same can be used for unix system using the hosts file

Comment: @PirateApp since this answer is accepted, I think it would make sense to remove "by an exe" from question title. The rules in this answer are system-wide, wereas reading your question my first thoughts were that you want this redirect only for your exe.

Comment: i am afraid it doesnt work, just got a chance to test it and it turns out that you cannot map ip to ip via hosts file https://superuser.com/questions/857862/mapping-one-ip-address-to-another-in-the-hosts-file